# Animating positions for short distances over long durations in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

Looking to incorporate some very subtle animations on a page (think clouds floating over a sky slowly).

```
$('DIV#clouds').animate( { left: '100px' }, 30 *1000 );
```

I tried implementing this in jQuery, and it seems jQuery can't do less than 1px increments (like flash can).  The animation works, it's just not smooth, it looks jumpy every time the cloud moves even a single pixel ever few milliseconds.

My assumption that subpixel moves are not possible, I am just asking hoping that I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the property `left` can only have whole pixels as a value. All jQuery does is add a pixel to the `left`  until it's at 100px. You cannot expect it to add half a pixel to animate smoother, sorry. 
Flash probably does this by using anti-aliasing.

Also, `{ left : '100px'}` should have single quotes around the px value.

Comment: So I assume this is a javascript/css/html limitation, and not necessarily a jQuery one, correct?

Comment: I'm interested in slow animations over properties which can have real values, such as `font-size`. Do you know how you might do that? Currently it just jumps jerkily between each integral pixel/point size.

Comment: I asked a related question about animating font sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304860/subtle-font-size-animation-over-short-distances-with-long-durations-in-jquery