# Subtle font size animation over short distances with long durations in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, font-size

I want to animate some text in a slow and subtle way. jQuery animations work with integer values, so if you want to animate a size over say 10px in two seconds, you see a series of small steps at five FPS which looks jerky.

Here's a [jsFiddle that shows what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/1/).

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827321/animating-positions-for-short-distances-over-long-durations-in-jquery) about animating positions, but the `top`/`left`/etc properties are integral, and so the accepted answer says it's not possible. However `font-size` *can* be animated as a real number, if jQuery will spit real numbers out.

I will also want to chain together a series of such animations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out this is quite hard! I've had some success in getting animation to work, but the browser seems to ignore non integer font sizes for large values (80-90 px). [Can you improve on this?](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/8/)

Comment: After playing around with that fiddle for the last hour I think the main problem is that font-size does not visually change much in between the decimal area. I think the smallest notable change is .5 of a pixel. If you are asking to increase the point or pixel by 10 over 2 seconds that works out at 0.005 pixels per millisecond. Seeing you only note a change in font-size at the next .5 you will only see a change every 100 milliseconds, hence it looks "laggy". Off course, making that 10 pixel change over a shorter period of time "Smoothes" out the animation.

Comment: you might try doing transforms instead of manipulating the text directly.

Comment: @FlavorScape, a colleague recommended something similar in a passing comment. Do you have something concrete I could start from? Even just a URL to some docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be direct manipulations css transformations - [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/22/) (I only included webkit css to make it readable, but similar functions exist in all modern browsers). The "ease-out" property includes the fast-then-slow functionality you were aiming for. It's certainly smoother than what you've been able to get so far, but it's quite blurry - not sure if it's a trade-off you'd want to make. And as it's an experimental property, you'd still probably want your existing jQuery animation as a fallback for older browsers.

Comment: That looks very smooth and takes duration into account as well. Very nice. I found this very hard to achieve with jQuery animation as there is a minimum increase in font-size which has to occur before the font-size visually changes.

Comment: This is very smooth -- giving the native iOS app that I'm trying to replicate a run for its money! As it zooms in, you can see some aliasing around the edge of the text though. Is it possible to start with a reduced version of a larger area, so that this aliasing isn't noticeable?

Comment: I should point out that I'm only really targetting WebKit via iOS on iPad, and Chrome on Android tablets.  Of course this is interesting in a general sense too.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the aliasing by [doubling the default font size, and halving the default scale](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/25/). This looks pretty close to what I need -- I'll revisit tomorrow.

Comment: I modified your code a little to [get the effect I wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/31/). It's lovely and smooooth now on Chrome, and I'll test it tomorrow on iOS. Thanks very much for pointing out this avenue!

Comment: No problem! The scale down at the start was a neat idea. I've done something similar for canvas transformations but never thought of giving it a go in css transforms; the effect was pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

I had another look a the minimum point value which is visually recognisable. The smallest unit for `pt` I noticed change in was `0.2pt`.

However, I noticed that when applying the change in steps of 0.2 points over a period of 1 millisecond per increment in a while loop that it still looked a little "laggy". May not if not running in jsfiddle though.

The point is that if you want to change the font-size smoothly by 10 points you must apply the change in steps of `0.2pt` or `0.25pt` or `0.5pt` (what ever you find smoothest) at a time and you then must use an interval of 1 to stay smooth but you should not apply a different interval as otherwise the incremental steps are to small to notice and the whole animation ends up choppy again.

I think trying to force this `10pt` change over 2 seconds will always look choppy no matter what framework you use, due to the lack of visual change on the font-size in the lower decimals.

This worked for me quite well:
*(I'm not taking decreasing font-size animation into account in this example but that can be added off course)*

```
function smoothAnimation($selector, startPoints, points){
    var increments = 0.2;
    var currentPoints = startPoints;
    var endPoints = currentPoints + points;

    while(currentPoints < endPoints){
        currentPoints += increments;
        $selector.animate({"font-size": currentPoints.toString() + "pt"}, 1, "swing");
    }
}

$('#msg').click(function() {
    $msg = $('#msg');
    $msg.animate({"font-size": "80pt"}, 400, "swing");

    smoothAnimation($msg, 80, 10);

    $msg.animate({"font-size": "40pt"}, 400, "swing");
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gyA8D/23/) - smooth(ish) font-size animation

To make it look smoother increase the `increments` value to `0.25` or even `0.5`. Ones you have nice smooth step you can set the points to any other value and the animation stays smooth as long as you don't force a 2 second animation interval.

Comment: This definitely looks better than the jQuery version I came up with. It still has a bit of jitter though. I'm actually trying to reproduce the smoothness of a native iOS app via HTML5, and even this solution isn't quite as smooth. As I left the office today a colleague suggested I look into some of the 3D transforms, in hope of getting this hardware accelerated via a texture. Sounds good, but I haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: I totally agree. I don't think any setting using jQuery `animate` will ever give you that smoothness. When you find a solution, please post it as I think this is a very interesting problem to solve. The transformation from `Bubbles`'s answer looks really nice and it lets you specify a duration :)

Comment: Actually I should clarify that I'm targetting iOS/WebKit. Your demo looks fantastic in Firefox, but on Chrome/iOS it doesn't look quite as good as the native iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animations are terrible. Look into another tweening solution that utilizes requestAnimationFrame technique or a better timing mechanism. Maybe try a tween lib like [tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/) look at the Rome demo, nice slow moving clouds...

Comment: I was able to get a smooth stream of real values via jQuery animation just fine, but the problem seems to be in the rendering of text.  Simply applying these numbers to the `text-size` property doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, only firefox has support for sub-pixel rendering of fonts, so animations in other browsers will always snap to pixel.